# Laravel 5 with Select2, Loading data with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, url, laravel-5, jquery-select2

first of all, here is my code so far.

My route:

```
Route::get('cities/citybylang/{lang_id}', [
        'uses'  => 'CitiesController@cityByLanguage',
        'as'    => 'dashboard.cityByLanguage'
]);
```

My controller:

```
public function cityByLanguage($lang_id){
    $cities = City::select('name','id')->where('lang_id',$lang_id)->get();

    return $cities;
}
```

My view select

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax">
  <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
</select>
```

My Select2 code

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
                  ajax: {
                    url: "/dashboard/cities/citybylang/1",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,

                    data: function (params) {
                        console.log(params.term);
                      return {
                        q: params.term, // search term
                        page: params.page,
                        name: params.name
                      };
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
                          console.log(settings.url);
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, page) {
                        console.log(data);

                      // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                      // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                      // alter the remote JSON data
                      return {
                        results: data
                      };
                    },
                    cache: true
                  },
                  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
                  minimumInputLength: 1,
                  templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
                  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
                });
            });


            function formatRepo (repo) {
                if (repo.loading) return repo.text;
                var markup = '<div class="clearfix">' +
                '<div clas="col-sm-10">' +
                '<div class="clearfix">' +
                '<div class="col-sm-6">' + repo.name + '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> ' + repo.name + '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-sm-2"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> ' + repo.name + '</div>' +
                '</div>';

                if (repo.name) {
                  markup += '<div>' + repo.name + '</div>';
                }

                markup += '</div></div>';

                return markup;
            }


            function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
                return repo.name || repo.text;
            }
```

Okey, the basic problem is, i can't pass the right parameter to the controller.
This is how this work now: I start typing to the select field and it give a list with the cities which has the lang_id = 1. 
**So the ajax call send this to the controller:** 
somthing.com/dashboard/cities/citybylang/1?q=[value, what i type to the select field]
**I have pretty url, so i want something like this:**
somthing.com/dashboard/cities/citybylang/[value, what i type to the select field]

So the question is, how can i pass parameter to the controller in the right way?

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but I was looking for same thing that's how I manged it.

```
url: function(params) {
    return '/some/url/' + params.term;
},
```

Here is reference link
https://select2.github.io/options.html